# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch /order/search/searchresults.asp, line 597

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am getting this error when I insert the postcode to search the shop, but if I reload the webpage it disappear. Could someone help me to fix it?
[postcode research](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjOGo.png)

```
ddd=0                       
if request.querystring("searchtype") = "postcode" then                          
    If objRds("longitude") & "" <> "" AND objRds("latitude") & "" <> "" Then                            
       ' Response.Write("lat1 " & coords(0) & " lon1 " & coords(1) & " [] lat2 " & objRds("latitude") & "  lon2 " & objRds("longitude") & "<br/>")                          


        ddd = round(distance(coords(0), coords(1), objRds("latitude"), objRds("longitude"), "M"),1)


'Response.Write("ddd " & ddd & "<br/>")                         
    End If                          
else
```

Comment: This code is very confusing. Can you clarify it? The line that starts with '**ddd=' is not vbscript, and what is 'If objRds("longitude") & "" <> "" AND objRds("latitude") & "" <> "" Then' supposed to check?

Answer (score 0):

```
ddd = round(distance(coords(0), coords(1), objRds("latitude"), objRds("longitude"), "M"),1)
```

chances are one of the parameters you're passing into the DISTANCE function are invalid. Do a Response.Write of each parameter and you'll likely find that one of them is blank or one of them is the wrong data type.